# Autocomplete show all results

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

Collect data from page `format.json`.

In JS I have:

```
$('input[name="q"]').autoComplete({
    source: function(term, response){
        $.getJSON('/search.json', { q: term }, function(data){ response(data); });
    }
});
```

For autocomplete I use this [plugin](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html).

**What is responsible for the output?**

I have in the autocomplete drop all the names. To fall out only need to apply. it is necessary to drop only those which coincide.

Is responsible for it `.indexOf(term)`? what to use?

[image]

The screen shows all the results (which have match and those who do not have a match). Need to see only those that have a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being you're getting the data from a JSON file you'll have to do the filtering on the client side. The way that it would work with an actual AJAX request to a server, you'd do the filtering on the server to only return the data you need (that's why you send the query term as a parameter).

So you will need to change your code to  look like this:

```
$('input[name="q"]').autoComplete({
    source: function (term, response) {
        $.getJSON('/search.json', function (data) {
            term = term.toLowerCase();
            var matches = [];
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                if (~data[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) matches.push(data[i]);
            response(matches);
        });
    }
});
```

You may need to do something different depending on what your `data` structure looks like but I'm *assuming* it's an array of strings

**EDIT**

If you want to limit your matches you can do it in the for loop rather than in the last line, this will be better for performance as it won't have to loop around once you've got 5 matches

```
$('input[name="q"]').autoComplete({
    source: function (term, response) {
        $.getJSON('/search.json', function (data) {
            term = term.toLowerCase();
            var matches = [];
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                if (~data[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term) && matches.length == 4) {
                    matches.push(data[i]);
                    break;
                }
            response(matches);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: variable `choices` must be an array of data? how to make it got there?

Comment: I want to show only top 5 values. Can we limit the number of dropdown items?

Comment: Of course, you can change the line `response(matches);` to `response(matches.slice(0,5));` Or see the edit if you're worried about performance.